# laravel validation, how to add validation rule on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, validation, laravel-5

```
//html code
<form>
<input type="radio" id="defult" name="price_type" value="default">
<label for="defult">Default Price</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="custom" name="price_type" value="custom">
<label for="custom">Custom Price</label><be>

<input placeholder="Custom Price" class="form-control" name="custom_price">
</form>

$('input[type=radio][name=price_type]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'default') {
        //make custom_price optional
    }
    else if (this.value == 'custom') {
        //make custom_price required
    }

});
```

Actually, I have a radio box for the custom price or default price, if the user selects the custom price then want to make input[name=custom_price] **required** or if the user selects default price then make input[name=custom_price] **optional**.

Comment: You can't use back-end validation on front-end code, but you can do that with XHR request like ajax, axios

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" id="default" name="price_type" value="default">
        <label for="default">Default Price</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="custom" name="price_type" value="custom">
        <label for="custom">Custom Price</label><br>
        <input placeholder="Custom Price" class="form-control" name="custom_price" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('input[type=radio][name=price_type]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'default') {
            //make custom_price optional
            $('input[name=custom_price]').prop('required', false);
        }
        else if (this.value == 'custom') {
            //make custom_price required
            $('input[name=custom_price]').prop('required', true);
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) that make the bridge between Laravel and [jqueryValidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).